How to iterate through a dictionary to get values on the lowest level?
Please help me understand how to extract the value of each ingredient for each product and do something with it. But for starters I just want to print them all one by one.
MENU = {
    "product_1": {
        "ingredients": {
            "ingredient_1": 50,
            "ingredient_2": 18
        },
        "cost": 1.5
    },
    "product_2": {
        "ingredients": {
            "ingredient_1": 200,
            "ingredient_2": 150,
            "ingredient_3": 24
        },
        "cost": 2.5
    }
}

I started with this code:
for ingredient in MENU:
   print(MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"])

but this prints out all 3 ingredients with their values for product_2 3 times. I need it to print out 200, 150, 24

for key,value in MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].items(): print(value)

Or print(MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].values())

Do you see that the loop variable ingredient is not actually used in the loop?  That's usually a sign that you've made some mistake.

As @John commented:
You need to get familiarized yourself with dictionary:
for key,value in MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].items():
  print(value)

or
for x in MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].values():
  print(x)

Output
200
150
24

If you just need a list:
list(MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].values())
#[200, 150, 24]


If you want all values, iterate over them as a hierarchy.
for products in MENU:
    for key,value in MENU[products]["ingredients"].items():
        print(value)

Check out this explanation about dictionaries in python with examples

You need to get the value from the iterated dictionary keys:
for ingredient in MENU:
   print(MENU[ingredient]["ingredients"].values())

Or if you just want from product_2:
print(MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].values())

If you want the keys:
print(list(MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"]))

Or:
print(MENU["product_2"]["ingredients"].keys())

